# Blogger minify cookiechoices

Tags: javascript, compression, blogger, minify

I'm currently optimizing a blog made with blogger and I was wondering if there's a way to minify the following file:
`blogname/js/cookiechoices.js`
Either a solution which prevents it from loading (so that I can download it, minify it and then upload it on my own), a solution that actually minifies it or a solution that replaces it with `blogname/js/cookiechoices.js` will be fine!

Comment: May be you should open a support ticket at blogger itself. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/blogger

Comment: I would suggest setting up CloudFlare (if you are using a custom domain) on your blog and then these files can be automatically minified via its Settings ( A working example - https://www.stylifyyourblog.com/js/cookiechoices.js )